# Can we reopen the question about a colony on Neptune?

Tags: discussion, reopening-questions

This question seems to have had some back and forth between WB and Astronomy.se:

[Potential Neptune Colony](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/237318/potential-neptune-colony)

It was closed due to needing clarity. I think it is answerable as it is, but I cannot vote to reopen it because it was closed by a moderator.

For reference, the question  is asking if a dirigible colony in Neptune is feasible, and the gravity people would feel there. That's it. I have some elaboration on how this is not realistically possible due to buoyancy problems and strong weather, even though where the pressure is 1 atm we would feel about 1G.

**Edit** nevermind, the question is a duplicate of [Could a colony on Neptune work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/182888/21222)

Comment: I still think it lacks details. One among them: feasible for which sort of capability framework?

Comment: @L.Dutch Is it possible however to make it commentable again? It's hard to believe John B will seek out help here on meta on how to reopen the post. Especially after these site switch didgeridoos ^^.

Comment: But the post is locked, so we cannot edit it to atleast add some details

Comment: Migrated questions, when closed, get bounced back to the community where they were written (and the OP didn't have an account here, so they won't see the comments anyway)

Comment: Looks like the question got migrated here twice. It's in a very strange state. Perhaps we should reach out to astronomy, about making sure that questions are suitable here before migrating. It's not good that the rest of Stack Exchange considers such a dumping ground that they'll migrate the same ticket to us twice.

Comment: @sphennings, it was migrated once and bounced back. no double migration. Once a migration is rejected from a site, any further attempt is not allowed.

Comment: @L.Dutch If you look at Astronomy's view of the question's history it records two separate migration to WB events with different moderators involved both times. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/50871/revisions

Comment: I wonder why it was done twice (?) btw that topic could have been accepted and closed  right  away because of duplicates on WB [could-a-colony-on-neptune-work](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/182888/could-a-colony-on-neptune-work) and for this case, especially [life-in-a-neptune-atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207676/life-in-a-neptune-atmosphere) When there's a reference in a comment, JohnB, the interested readers or answerers could click one of these links and proceed..

Comment: @sphennings, if you look the chronology of that question from this side, you see only 1 migration

Comment: @L.Dutch IDK. I saw the WB question history. Normally rejected migrations return to the originating site. They don't stick around. I've never seen a question with two separate migrations to the same site before. I lack the observability tools to on both sites to really do anything more than remark, that *it feels strange*.

Answer (score 1):

#### No

The query, as it currently stands at Astronomy, reads: *I am currently writing a medium-length sci-fi story for a school project, and my hope is to make it as realistic as possible. I was wondering if a dirigible-based Neptune colony is feasible and what the G forces would be exerted on the inhabitants?*

> I am currently writing a medium-length sci-fi story for a school project, and my hope is to make it as realistic as possible.

So far, so good. This is the only on topic part of this query! Sadly, that's not enough to go on.

> I was wondering if a dirigible-based Neptune colony is feasible

As written, this is not sufficiently *fictional* for WB. In other words, there is not worldbuilding context that would make this query on topic for us as opposed to SpaceExploration.SE.

If the OP were exploring a near future hard SF and wanted to provide their scientific / geopolitical / technological / fantastic context then that would make this particular question a reality check.

> what the G forces would be exerted on the inhabitants?

This is not on topic for WB.SE as it is essentially asking for real planetary data.

**Conclusion:** Any query *can* be reopened. The question that needs to be asked is always "ought this query be reopened without any kind of improvement". This query fails on this account.

This query suffers from several problems: the OP is asking too many questions (I see two and possibly three very distinct ones); one of the questions is entirely off topic for this community, and the other question is off topic for the community where the question currently resides; the part of the question that would be on topic here suffers from a lack of context and would immediately be closed.

**Solution:** The OP should edit his question on Astronomy to focus on the planetary data (leaving out the SF story rationale) and write a separate question here in WB focusing on the fictional elements. If by "feasibility" of such a colony he means various governmental, corporate, economic factors, that might be a third question to ask in SpaceEx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is in a really strange state. The question, despite showing that it is currently returned back to Astronomy Stackexchange, is still on the Worldbuilding Site.[image]

Okay, so basically to be honest, it was actually me who had suggested the migration, back on the Astronomy Stackexchange. My suggestion was rejected (the red circle), but soon a moderator on that website migrated that question to the site.[image]

The strange thing however, is that the OP's profile, JohnB's is unclickable, which either suggests that his profile is banned, or that it is just some glitch with my computer.

I would suggest that it should either be migrated to Space-Exploration stackexchange, but the sci-fi background doesn't help much. So what I think best is to wait for OP to add some more details to the question so that it can be clarified. Then, since I am not a mod/admin, we should leave it best to the moderators to decide whether it should be deleted/migrated or remain closed.

Comment: The user in unclickable because they don't have a worldbuilding account. And bad questions should not be migrated without being improved.

Comment: No, don't suggest migrations. Migrations aren't for "hot potato" questions to just pass onto the next stack and maybe pass them again. Only *high quality* questions that are *already on-topic* on the target site should be migrated. If the question is not in a tip-top shape, then a migration is just passing the problem onto somebody else. We don't do that. Conversely, that means that even if a question seems good, *you* should be intimately familiar with the target site and its rules before suggesting a migration, as well. As you have to be certain it would be accepted.

Comment: I concur that migrating a poorly written question doesn't solve anything. My suggestion is for you to go back to Astronomy and invite JohnB to consider my solution that I suggested in my answer.